# Configuring DBMail with SQL Server (2005) Management Studio Express

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005, email

The title sums up my dilemma:

"Configuring DBMail with SQL Server Management Studio Express"

Anyone out in this august assemblage can help me out?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know , sql server express does not have DBMail feature.

However I have seen this blog and after some configuration I had it working.

http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/mladenp/archive/2007/07/01/60245.aspx

**Note:** I did get into few issues so I upgraded my version to SQl Server professional. I recommend you do the same. You may hack express and have it working but you will face issues in the future because it is not meant to work with this version.